# In Graphvi How to change the length of self-looped edge?

Tags: graphviz

I just need to write a small graph. Below is the code:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;     
    nodesep=1.0;
    node [shape = circle];  
    S -> S [ label = "0.67" ];  
    S -> H [ label = "0.24" ];  
    S -> C [ label = "0.09" ];

    H -> H [ label = "0.82" ];      
    H -> S [ label = "0.15" ];
    H -> C [ label = "0.03" ];

    C -> C [ label = "0.45" ];      
    C -> S [ label = "0.33" ];
    C -> H [ label = "0.22" ];
}
```

However, the output graph is not what I want. As you can see, the self-looped edges are too long. It looks not good. How can I fix this problem?

[image: graphviz output]

Answer (score 2):

It looks slightly better if you set the position of the self referential arrow to :ne, for example:

```
digraph G {
A:ne -> A:ne
A->B
}
```

You can also change the graph nodesep attribute to a low value:

```
graph [nodesep=.15]
A:e -> A:e
A ->B
```

However this would change the node separation for the whole graph and might not always be desirable. Also, it only seems to work with the link position on the East.